# Using Uri constructor return you a invalid uri

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uri, filepath

```
ImagePath = "C:Document.jpg"  
Uri filePath = new Uri(ImagePath)
```

Above is my code. However, it will throw me an "Invalid URI: dos path has not been rooted. example C:. I am wondering if there is anything I can do using URI constructor overload to avoid this to happen?
I also want to know better about this error message. In what case and why it doesn't take C: but instead accepting only C:\?? If I use a network drive, for example, my network drive path is "\NetworkDriveA\Document.jpg", is that possible for this error to happen?

Comment: try c:\Document.jpg

Comment: All the paths you've specified are invalid. It should be `C:\Document.jpg` and `\\NetworkDriveA\Document.jpg`. The reason it doesn't accept the paths is because they can't exist.